# angular 2: rxjs forkJoin http error continue stream

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I'm calling 2 services in a `forkJoin`, the second service may fail, but I want the `stream` to continue if the second service does fails.

What I have so far:

```
Observable.forkJoin([
    this.http.get('/service1'),
    this.http.get('/service2').catch(error => Observable.empty())
])
    .do(([result1, result2]: any[]) => {
        //When service2 fails, I never get in here with .empty()

    })
```

`Observable.of(undefined)` or `Observable.of(error)` works. But, I was under the impression that returning just an `empty Observable` from the `catch` would make the call fail silently and the stream would continue?

How can I ensure that the stream continues if service2 fails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Observable.empty()` simply invoke `complete` method of `observer` object, so it does not do anything else.
And this is how `forkJoin` work:

> When all observables complete emit the last value from each.

`Observable.empty()` does not have any last value, so `forkJoin` cannot know how to `emit the last value`. if you `Observable.of(undefined)` this mean, you call `next` method with `undefined` then `complete` method will call. so the last value is `undefined`.

> How can I ensure that the stream continues if service2 fails?

you can add error handler and complete handler for testing purpose.

Demo here: http://jsbin.com/babirakiyi/1/edit?js,console

Thank [@Yury Tarabanko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351705/yury-tarabanko) for test case:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/524259a9bf2154824ddced89efc71c2e4149b2a9/spec/observables/forkJoin-spec.ts#L165-L174

Comment: +1 There is even test case checking `forkJoin` not emit if any source is empty https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/spec/observables/forkJoin-spec.ts#L165